# Print Multiple Backslashes

Tags: java

I'm trying to make this code print a input such as "\b\t\n\r" . The issue is when I try to replace a single slash with a double slash so that the single backslash prints in front of each letter, I get some text which makes no sense as a output. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public static String escape(String input) {
    input = input.replace("\"", "\\");
    return input;
}
```

Comment: The string literal `"\b\t\n\r"` is not an 8-character string. It is a 4-character string with a backspace, tab, newline, and carriage-return, all of which are non-displayable, i.e. they move the cursor but don't print anything. If you want a string of those 8 characters, double the backslashes: `"\\b\\t\\n\\r"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code sample you are trying to replace a single " symbol by a single slash. It should be if I understand you correctly:

```
input.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

In addition, string like "\n" does not contains slash, due to "\n" is the special symbol, not just two symbols. This could affect your code too.

Comment: thank you, didnt realize \n itself was the special character

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but why not write your own replace method? It's pretty simple, and I made it specific for this case. I'm sure you could generalize it :)

```
String s = "";
for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    char c = input.charAt(i)
    if(c == '\')
    {
        s = s + "\\";
        i++;
    }
    else{
        s+=c;
    }
}
```